# How to nest form data

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

I want to have the following json example:

```
{
    attachments: {
        file: [
            { name: 'pic1.jpg' },
            { name: 'pic2.png' }
        ], 
        username: 'Test',
        age: 1
    }
}
```

is this possible in formdata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i figured it out. Just pass another key before array key... like:

```
fd = new FormData();
const files = [{...}, {...}, ...]
files.map(file => {
    fd.append("attachments[] file[]", file.name)    
});
fd.append("attachments[] name", 'Test')
fd.append("attachments[] age", 1)
```